Insulation testing circuits which are the output of a solid-state relay
I am looking at the tests in IEC 61010.
F.4 requires floating circuits to have an insulation test carried out at a minimum of 350 V AC (live and neutral joined, and 350 V AC connected between L+N and exposed conductive parts).
I have a couple of questions regarding how you do this if my output circuit is controlled using an Omron G3PJ-family SSR:

This will effectively connect 350 V AC between the SSR output and the system's protective earth. Will that damage the SSR?
Are these outputs not classified as floating outputs because the SSR is loosely coupling this output to the system's ground?

For (2), I think that cannot be the case, on reflection. I suspect that the intention of 601010 is to insulation test all hazardous circuits. Switched outputs will not be tested as part of the supply terminals insulation test, so they need to be tested separately.
This is a schematic of the test circuit that 61010 requires (The symbols aren't quite right for an AC SSR as I can't work out how to get the stack exchange circuit editor to quite give me what I want)

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

A very warm welcome to the site. For your SSR, please add a manufacturer, full part number and a link to the datasheet (links can be embedded, see the icons). Please edit this information into your question, do not add new info as comments. Thanks.

I've never used or even seen an SSR that has an earth connection.

@Finbarr, agreed, hence 'can we have a part and datasheet' before the usual lengthy guesswork comment chains spring up without any basis to go from :-)

Your SSR will have live input from mains and live output to load connected to it anyway. Or neutral input from mains and neutral output to load. Depend on if you connect it in series with the load on the live or neutral wire.
If you have a path to Earth/Ground from any mains in/out terminal, your SSR or design is flawed already and that can't happen or it will trip the GFCI/RCD.
So your SSR has to anyway withstand mains AC on mains terminals without leaking to some metal plate on it that will be bolted to earthed metal chassis. If it handles normal AC but not the rated test voltage, it won't pass the test.
So the SSR should not be loosely coupling anything from mains terminals to ground.
